# ¿Cómo modifico mi código para leer palabras, en vez de letras?

Tags: c++

Tengo un problema con mi código, lee caracteres. Pero quiero modificar para que lea palabras.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int a,b;
    char e[20], c;
    cout<<"Por favor ingrese 10 nombres\n";
    for(a=1;a<11;a++)
    {
        cout<<"Ingrese  Nombre  "<<a<<": ";
        cin>>e[a];
    }

    for(a=1;a<10;a++)
    {
        for(b=1;b<10;b++)
        {
            if(e[b]>e[b+1])
            {
              c=e[b+1];
              e[b+1]=e[b];
              e[b]=c;
            }
        }
    }

   ofstream archivo;
    archivo.open ("orden.txt");   //Crea archivo .txt
    archivo <<"Nombres Ordenados Alfabeticamente:\n";
   cout <<"Nombres Ordenados Alfabeticamente:\n";
   for(a=1;a<11;a++)
     {
            cout <<e[a]<<endl;          //Imprime en pantalla
            archivo <<e[a]<<endl;       //Escribe en archivo .txt
     }

   archivo.close();
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que deberías hacer es ocupar `string` en tu caso que quieres leer 10 nombres solo cambia `char[10]` por `string[10]`

Answer (score 3):

El problema principal es que estas declarando un array de caracteres llamado `e` que sirve para almacenar una cadena o palabra pero con tu código pretendes meter en el varias palabras, es decir cadenas de caracteres.

Para poder hacer esto tienes que declarar un array de cadenas (un array que contiene dentro arrays de caracteres), es decir, usar un array bidimencional. Para declarar un array que pueda almacenar 10 nombres de un máximo de 19 caracteres cada uno (el último espacio se usa para el caracter nulo) hacemos lo siguiente:

```
char e[10][20];
```

Por otro lado es recomendable que empieces siempre a leer un arreglo desde el indice 0 no desde el uno como haces en tu código, te evitarás problemas futuros. Este sería tu código para leer los 20 nombres y almacenarlos en el array:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a;
    char e[10][20];
    cout<<"Por favor ingrese 10 nombres\n";

    for(a=0;a<10;a++)
    {
        cout<<"Ingrese  Nombre  "<<a+1<<": ";
        cin>>e[a];
    }

return 0;
}
```

Una segunda forma es usar la libreria estandar [`string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) que facilita el manejo de cadenas en C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int a;
    string e[10];
    cout<<"Por favor ingrese 10 nombres\n";
    for(a=0;a<10;a++)
    {
    cout<<"Ingrese  Nombre  "<<a+1<<": ";
    cin>>e[a];
    }

return 0;
}
```

Puedes usar tambien la biblioteca  [`vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) junto a [`string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a;
    vector<string> e;
    string entrada;
    cout<<"Por favor ingrese 10 nombres\n";
    for(a=0;a<3;a++)
    {
        cout<<"Ingrese  Nombre  "<<a+1<<": ";
        cin>>entrada;
        e.push_back(entrada);
    }
return 0;
}
```

Se puede hacer también usando punteros junto a string o arrays de char.

No se lo que pretendes hacer con el código:

```
for(a=1;a<10;a++)
{
    for(b=1;b<10;b++)
    {
        if(e[b]>e[b+1])
        {
          c=e[b+1];
          e[b+1]=e[b];
          e[b]=c;
        }
    }
}
```

Por lo que me he centrado en la entrada solamente, si tienes problemas con el resto edita tu pregunta diciendo que se supone que hace el resto de tu código.

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

El `operator>>` lee una cosa u otra dependiendo del tipo del segundo operando:

```
char c;
cin >> c; // Lee el siguiente carácter.

int i;
cin >> i; // Lee un número.

char c[20];
cin >> c[3]; // Lee un carácter, ya que `c[3]` es el 3er cáracter de c
```

¿Y para leer palabras? Utiliza `string`s.

```
string str; // Necesitas `#include <string>`
cin >> str; // Lee la siguiente palabra.
```

A la hora de leer la siguiente palabra, si lo primero que se encuentra `cin` (o cualquier flujo), son espacios, los espacios se ignoran, y no se guardan en `str`. La palabra recuperada comienza en el primer carácter que no sea espacio (o salto de línea, etc), y termina en el siguiente espacio (o salto de línea, etc).

El espacio o salto de línea que haya al final de la palabra encontrada en el flujo, tampoco se guarda en `str`.